# Cannot solve a system of linear equations

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I have four known functions, $u_i(x)$, and I suspect that all these four functions satisfy an operator, through a common force function, or at least a common force function type $(h(x)$, with some parameters, where each parameter could be adapted to the operator.

The "native" (unparametrized) operator is:

\begin{equation} \label{NLS_operator}
    P_i:=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+|u_i(x)|^2
\end{equation}

$i=1,2,3,4$, the index of the respective known function. These functions are Fourier series ($L^2$ functions), and they are very long.
See them at the bottom of this post.
I would like to prepare a system of ODEs which are formed by the equation:

\begin{equation}  
    P_{\beta_i} u_i(x)=h_i(x)
\end{equation}
$\beta$ is the parameter that we multiply to the operator (for simplicity) or we can consider it as a nonlinear term (function) which we add to the operator and $h(x)$ are the unknown force functions, $h$.

Here the force function $h$ should be in the form $$h(x)=Ae^{-\lambda(x-x_0)^2}.$$

Since I have four  known $u(x)=\{u_1, u_2, u_3, u_4\}$, I should get:

$$P_{\beta} u_1(x)=h(x)\\
P_{\beta} u_1(x)=h(x)\\P_{\beta} u_3(x)=h(x)\\P_{\beta} u_4(x)=h(x)$$

With $$h(x)=Ae^{-\lambda(x-x_0)^2}$$

so we  have three unknowns, $A$, $\lambda$ and $x_0$ plus the unknown parameter $\beta$. This makes 4 unknowns,and four linear equations.

**Example 1:**
Let for example $u_1=e^{2it}$, $u_2=e^{4it}$, $u_3=e^{-3it}$ and $u_4=e^{-5it}$.
Then we get the prepared inputs :

```
d[t_] = E^(2*I*t)
D2d[t_] = D[d[t],{t,2}]
```

The second

```
g[t_] = E^(4*I*t)
D2g[t_] = D[g[t],{t,2}]
```

the third:

```
b[t_] = E^(-3*I*t)
D2b[t_] = D[b[t],{t,2}]
```

and the fourth:

```
u[t_] = E^(-5*I*t)
D2u[t_] = D[u[t],{t,2}]
```

Then we arrange this such that we can solve for $\lambda$, $\beta$ , $x_0$ and $A$.

For this use `Solve` do:

```
Solve[{-1/2*D2d[t] + (Abs[d[t]])^2*d[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ (t - B))^2/β,
  -1/2*D2g[t] + (Abs[g[t]])^2*g[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ (t - B))^2/β,
  -1/2*D2b[t] + (Abs[b[t]])^2*b[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ (t - B))^2/β,
  -1/2*D2u[t] + (Abs[u[t]])^2*u[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ (t - B))^2/β}, {B, A, β, λ}]
```

With this I get NO result.

**Here is the actual question I am seeking an answer for**

Let the given functions be $u_1=d(t),u_2=g(t),u_3=b(t), u_4=u(t)$ given below

```
d[t_] = 139.85 + (15.8404 + 4.76022 I) E^(-I t) + (15.8404 - 
      4.76022 I) E^(I t) + (4.64917 - 
      3.3024 I) E^(-2 I t) + (4.64917 + 
      3.3024 I) E^(2 I t) + (7.42191 - 
      0.300123 I) E^(-3 I t) + (7.42191 + 
      0.300123 I) E^(3 I t) + (0.340877 - 
      2.54665 I) E^(-4 I t) + (0.340877 + 
      2.54665 I) E^(4 I t) + (7.72422 + 
      6.71332 I) E^(-5 I t) + (7.72422 - 
      6.71332 I) E^(5 I t) + (3.16511 - 
      9.14479 I) E^(-6 I t) + (3.16511 + 
      9.14479 I) E^(6 I t) + (3.31502 + 
      2.18874 I) E^(-7 I t) + (3.31502 - 
      2.18874 I) E^(7 I t) + (9.31827 + 
      6.94538 I) E^(-8 I t) + (9.31827 - 
      6.94538 I) E^(8 I t) + (5.87173 + 
      18.8341 I) E^(-9 I t) + (5.87173 - 
      18.8341 I) E^(9 I t) + (8.75949 + 
      14.7107 I) E^(-10 I t) + (8.75949 - 
      14.7107 I) E^(10 I t) + (19.2903 + 
      7.78329 I) E^(-11 I t) + (19.2903 - 
      7.78329 I) E^(11 I t) - (3.39063 - 
      18.5502 I) E^(-12 I t) - (3.39063 + 
      18.5502 I) E^(12 I t) + (3.58427 + 
      18.7438 I) E^(-13 I t) + (3.58427 - 
      18.7438 I) E^(13 I t) + (2.66129 + 
      20.0781 I) E^(-14 I t) + (2.66129 - 
      20.0781 I) E^(14 I t) - (8.46335 - 
      9.96867 I) E^(-15 I t) - (8.46335 + 
      9.96867 I) E^(15 I t) - (8.50037 - 
      1.20377 I) E^(-16 I t) - (8.50037 + 
      1.20377 I) E^(16 I t) - (1.36102 - 
      16.9315 I) E^(-17 I t) - (1.36102 + 
      16.9315 I) E^(17 I t) - (5.78964 - 
      2.96094 I) E^(-18 I t) - (5.78964 + 
      2.96094 I) E^(18 I t) + (2.14681 + 
      8.29635 I) E^(-19 I t) + (2.14681 - 
      8.29635 I) E^(19 I t) - (3.91145 - 
      10.7712 I) E^(-20 I t) - (3.91145 + 10.7712 I) E^(20 I t);
g[t_] = 13.87 + (9.25477 + 1.51787 I) E^(-I t) + (9.25477 - 
      1.51787 I) E^(I t) + (1.08996 + 
      0.300406 I) E^(-2 I t) + (1.08996 - 
      0.300406 I) E^(2 I t) - (1.96638 + 
      1.26469 I) E^(-3 I t) - (1.96638 - 
      1.26469 I) E^(3 I t) + (0.218112 - 
      0.308038 I) E^(-4 I t) + (0.218112 + 
      0.308038 I) E^(4 I t) + (1.90783 + 
      1.17281 I) E^(-5 I t) + (1.90783 - 
      1.17281 I) E^(5 I t) + (1.09081 + 
      0.353231 I) E^(-6 I t) + (1.09081 - 
      0.353231 I) E^(6 I t) + (0.173557 - 
      1.10369 I) E^(-7 I t) + (0.173557 + 
      1.10369 I) E^(7 I t) + (0.224736 - 
      0.475649 I) E^(-8 I t) + (0.224736 + 
      0.475649 I) E^(8 I t) + (0.215461 + 
      0.922754 I) E^(-9 I t) + (0.215461 - 
      0.922754 I) E^(9 I t) + (0.127993 + 
      0.559526 I) E^(-10 I t) + (0.127993 - 
      0.559526 I) E^(10 I t) + (0.557846 - 
      0.59431 I) E^(-11 I t) + (0.557846 + 
      0.59431 I) E^(11 I t) + (0.801299 - 
      0.286539 I) E^(-12 I t) + (0.801299 + 
      0.286539 I) E^(12 I t) + (0.301617 + 
      0.825404 I) E^(-13 I t) + (0.301617 - 
      0.825404 I) E^(13 I t) + (0.115336 + 
      0.833234 I) E^(-14 I t) + (0.115336 - 
      0.833234 I) E^(14 I t) + (0.786769 + 
      0.0749826 I) E^(-15 I t) + (0.786769 - 
      0.0749826 I) E^(15 I t) + (1.03796 - 
      0.0574653 I) E^(-16 I t) + (1.03796 + 
      0.0574653 I) E^(16 I t) + (0.302552 + 
      0.238826 I) E^(-17 I t) + (0.302552 - 
      0.238826 I) E^(17 I t) + (0.032363 + 
      0.135126 I) E^(-18 I t) + (0.032363 - 
      0.135126 I) E^(18 I t) + (0.952115 - 
      0.0508812 I) E^(-19 I t) + (0.952115 + 
      0.0508812 I) E^(19 I t) + (1.59932 + 
      0.164806 I) E^(-20 I t) + (1.59932 - 0.164806 I) E^(20 I t);
b[t_] = 22.2253 + (6.05951 + 1.26288 I) E^(-I t) + (6.05951 - 
      1.26288 I) E^(I t) - (2.28516 + 
      0.718175 I) E^(-2 I t) - (2.28516 - 
      0.718175 I) E^(2 I t) + (3.48496 + 
      1.91013 I) E^(-3 I t) + (3.48496 - 
      1.91013 I) E^(3 I t) + (1.02469 - 
      1.28294 I) E^(-4 I t) + (1.02469 + 
      1.28294 I) E^(4 I t) + (1.18499 + 
      0.102604 I) E^(-5 I t) + (1.18499 - 
      0.102604 I) E^(5 I t) + (1.05572 + 
      0.532558 I) E^(-6 I t) + (1.05572 - 
      0.532558 I) E^(6 I t) + (1.43148 - 
      1.00592 I) E^(-7 I t) + (1.43148 + 
      1.00592 I) E^(7 I t) + (1.14346 + 
      1.19477 I) E^(-8 I t) + (1.14346 - 
      1.19477 I) E^(8 I t) + (1.43917 + 
      0.795927 I) E^(-9 I t) + (1.43917 - 
      0.795927 I) E^(9 I t) + (1.91234 + 
      2.80903 I) E^(-10 I t) + (1.91234 - 
      2.80903 I) E^(10 I t) + (3.70871 + 
      2.25491 I) E^(-11 I t) + (3.70871 - 
      2.25491 I) E^(11 I t) + (3.20857 + 
      0.708758 I) E^(-12 I t) + (3.20857 - 
      0.708758 I) E^(12 I t) - (0.407118 - 
      0.0128365 I) E^(-13 I t) - (0.407118 + 
      0.0128365 I) E^(13 I t) + (0.747326 + 
      0.854073 I) E^(-14 I t) + (0.747326 - 
      0.854073 I) E^(14 I t) - (1.65033 - 
      1.69294 I) E^(-15 I t) - (1.65033 + 
      1.69294 I) E^(15 I t) - (1.70632 - 
      1.04809 I) E^(-16 I t) - (1.70632 + 
      1.04809 I) E^(16 I t) + (1.05899 + 
      1.95888 I) E^(-17 I t) + (1.05899 - 
      1.95888 I) E^(17 I t) + (1.36781 - 
      0.334041 I) E^(-18 I t) + (1.36781 + 
      0.334041 I) E^(18 I t) + (1.98706 - 
      0.0544715 I) E^(-19 I t) + (1.98706 + 
      0.0544715 I) E^(19 I t) + (0.890154 + 
      0.772225 I) E^(-20 I t) + (0.890154 - 0.772225 I) E^(20 I t);
u[t_] = 93.2259 + (9.87447 + 1.23806 I) E^(-I t) + (9.87447 - 
      1.23806 I) E^(I t) - (7.28392 + 
      0.41437 I) E^(-2 I t) - (7.28392 - 
      0.41437 I) E^(2 I t) + (12.8921 - 
      2.58731 I) E^(-3 I t) + (12.8921 + 
      2.58731 I) E^(3 I t) - (2.22197 - 
      2.18978 I) E^(-4 I t) - (2.22197 + 
      2.18978 I) E^(4 I t) + (11.0601 - 
      0.575458 I) E^(-5 I t) + (11.0601 + 
      0.575458 I) E^(5 I t) - (1.22048 - 
      2.68096 I) E^(-6 I t) - (1.22048 + 
      2.68096 I) E^(6 I t) + (6.47151 + 
      1.21344 I) E^(-7 I t) + (6.47151 - 
      1.21344 I) E^(7 I t) + (0.260353 + 
      4.33147 I) E^(-8 I t) + (0.260353 - 
      4.33147 I) E^(8 I t) + (0.61904 + 
      3.37889 I) E^(-9 I t) + (0.61904 - 
      3.37889 I) E^(9 I t) - (0.585492 - 
      2.98757 I) E^(-10 I t) - (0.585492 + 
      2.98757 I) E^(10 I t) + (1.95162 + 
      8.81749 I) E^(-11 I t) + (1.95162 - 
      8.81749 I) E^(11 I t) + (0.534066 + 
      11.0168 I) E^(-12 I t) + (0.534066 - 
      11.0168 I) E^(12 I t) - (1.45227 - 
      11.017 I) E^(-13 I t) - (1.45227 + 
      11.017 I) E^(13 I t) - (0.987428 - 
      6.69947 I) E^(-14 I t) - (0.987428 + 
      6.69947 I) E^(14 I t) - (4.88124 - 
      6.62883 I) E^(-15 I t) - (4.88124 + 
      6.62883 I) E^(15 I t) - (2.56445 - 
      4.71859 I) E^(-16 I t) - (2.56445 + 
      4.71859 I) E^(16 I t) - (4.16251 - 
      5.0285 I) E^(-17 I t) - (4.16251 + 
      5.0285 I) E^(17 I t) - (3.24296 - 
      2.11604 I) E^(-18 I t) - (3.24296 + 
      2.11604 I) E^(18 I t) - (4.22329 - 
      0.335417 I) E^(-19 I t) - (4.22329 + 
      0.335417 I) E^(19 I t) + (0.506471 - 
      0.205546 I) E^(-20 I t) + (0.506471 + 0.205546 I) E^(20 I t);
```

Then we declare the second differential operator:

```
D2u[t_] = D[u[t], {t, 2}];
D2b[t_] = D[b[t], {t, 2}];
D2g[t_] = D[g[t], {t, 2}];
D2d[t_] = D[d[t], {t, 2}];
```

and we prepare the system of algebraic equations:

```
 sys=[{-1/2*D2d[t] + (Abs[d[t]])^2*d[t] == 
       A*E^(-λ*I* (t - B))^2/β,
      -1/2*D2g[t] + (Abs[g[t]])^2*g[t] == 
       A*E^(-λ*I* (t - B))^2/β,
      -1/2*D2b[t] + (Abs[b[t]])^2*b[t] == 
       A*E^(-λ *I*(t - B))^2/β,
      -1/2*D2u[t] + (Abs[u[t]])^2*u[t] == 
       A*E^(-λ *I*(t - B))^2/β}, {B, A, β, λ}]
```

How can I solve this system?

`NSolve` Does not work, `Reduce` gives *"This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce."*,
and `Solve` seems not to converge..

An idea is to dicretize the functions $u$ into a set of vectors, and then use these discretized functions to identify the force functions $h$. But this I am not sure may work?

With Alex's suggestion, we obtain:

```
D2u[t_] = D[u[t], {t, 2}];
D2y[t_] = D[y[t], {t, 2}];
D2g[t_] = D[g[t], {t, 2}];
D2d[t_] = D[d[t], {t, 2}];
Du[t_] = D[u[t], {t, 1}];
Dy[t_] = D[y[t], {t, 1}];
Dg[t_] = D[g[t], {t, 1}];
Dd[t_] = D[d[t], {t, 1}];
NSolve[{-1/2*D2d[t] + (Abs[d[t]])^2*d[t] + I*u[t]*Du[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ *I*(t - B))^2/β,
  -1/2*D2g[t] + (Abs[g[t]])^2*g[t] + I*g[t]*Dg[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ*I* (t - B))^2/β,
  -1/2*D2y[t] + (Abs[y[t]])^2*y[t] + I*y[t]*Dy[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ *I*(t - B))^2/β,
  -1/2*D2u[t] + (Abs[u[t]])^2*u[t] + I*d[t]*Dd[t] == 
   A*E^(-λ *I*(t - B))^2/β},
 {B, A, β, λ}]
```

However, there are no changes currently, `NSolve` is running for hours.

Comment: Solve gives results in the form {{B -> ..., A -> ..., ...}, ...}, so it should be clear which solution corresponds to which unknown. For me, your code doesn't work and Solve just returns an empty List (Windows, Mathematica 13.0).

Comment: Ok, now I understand, the output you get is just the functions you entered. d[t], D2d[t], g[t], .... You can surpress it by putting a semicolon after the input, for example "d[t_]=e^(2*I*t);". The actual output from Solve is the empty brackets in the last line "{}", which means that Solve didn't find any Solution.

Comment: You'll have to investigate why there is no solution. If you're sure that a solution exists for your particular set of functions, you could try solving a simplified version of your problem first or a numerical solution to find out what's going on.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is, that you wrote "e^(...)". What you probably mean is "Exp[...]", because lowercase e by default is not defined to be Euler's number, only uppercase E, so alternatively you could write E^(...).

Comment: @banone it gave the same result, by changing to E^

Comment: Basically you have `A*E^(-\[Lambda] (t - B))^2/\[Beta]` set equal to four different expressions. There would certainly be no solutions for `{B, A, \[Beta], \[Lambda]}` as the variables, except possibly for special values of `t` (probably not, since it reduces to three equations in one unknown). -- You should change the `e^` to `E^` in the question. Copying nonworking is discouraging.

Comment: @MichaelE2 why sholdn't it be possible to solve this system of equations?There are four eqns and four unknowns, that is the basic recipe. e's corrected to E's

Comment: Your functions are complex, your forces are real. No wonder you get no solution.

Comment: @yarchik great point. I tried with multiplying I in the exponent of the force function , but NSolve gives no output, and Reduce does not work. So far Solve is running, but not certain it will give an output.

Comment: Equations that are not overdetermined may still be inconsistent. Small example (2 eqs, 2 unknowns): $1 = x+y,\ 2 = x+y$; $x+y$ cannot simulataneously be $1$ and $2$, even though there are two degrees of freedom on the face of it.

Comment: @yarchik Isn't the imaginary part zero?  (Numerically it was so on a test, IIRC.)

Comment: NSolve works, but takes ages.

Comment: @Vangsnes Where this model come from?

Comment: @AlexTrounev the equation is the nonliinear Schrödinger equation, while the Gaussian shaped function is a regular Gaussian function. However, the long functions are Fourier series of piecewise functions of wave-trains

Comment: @Vangsnes Original waves depends on time as well in a form $u=u(x-v t)$, therefore operator  $P$ should be as follows$\begin{equation} \label{NLS_operator}
    P_i:=i v\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+|u_i(x)|^2
\end{equation}$

Comment: @AlexTrounev This is a stationary equation, time dimension is neglected. It is like a snapshot in time, the profile of the wave , considered only at a moment. The time-dependent wave-train is scaled by the velocity of the wave-train. So we obtain a position-dependent solution. (sec*meter/sec=position)

Comment: @Vangsnes From the other hand your series are time dependent. So you need take into account time. What is the difference if you add  $iv d/dx$?

Comment: @Vangsnes These are scaled by the wave velocity. So they are no longer-time dependent, but weak solutions to the NLSE. I will try your suggestion. I update the post with it. I use variable $t$ bu in fact, it is the same as the variable $x$. The functions are just scaled Fourier tranasforms of the time-series piecewise constant functions

Comment: I did not read all comments. May be someone mentioned this. But why do you call these linear equations? They are not linear in variables you want to solve for.

Comment: It is clear that "This system cannot be solved with the methods available". There is no hope of getting a closed-form solution. You need to scale back your expectations of a "solution". This depends on exactly what you are trying to accomplish here.  A piece of advice. For testing purposes use only the first two terms of your functions. For example, use `d[t_] = 139.85 + (15.8404+4.76022 I)E^(-I t)` and so on.

Comment: @Somos I did that, and that also did not converge. I used the simplest forms of the functions, $E^{It}$, $E^{2It}$, $E^{3It}$, $E^{4It}$. Still no solution. Which is rather disappointing. Maybe Nasser's point is the cause of why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on it, FWIW:

The system to be solved is

```
{-1/2*D2d[t] + (Abs[d[t]])^2*d[t] == 
                                       A*E^(-λ*I* (t - B))^2/β,
 -1/2*D2g[t] + (Abs[g[t]])^2*g[t] == 
                                       A*E^(-λ*I* (t - B))^2/β,
 -1/2*D2b[t] + (Abs[b[t]])^2*b[t] == 
                                       A*E^(-λ *I*(t - B))^2/β,
 -1/2*D2u[t] + (Abs[u[t]])^2*u[t] == 
                                       A*E^(-λ *I*(t - B))^2/β}
```

Its form is

$$\eqalign{
\text{LHS}(d(t)) &= \text{RHS}(B,A,\beta,\lambda,t) \cr
\text{LHS}(g(t)) &= \text{RHS}(B,A,\beta,\lambda,t) \cr
\text{LHS}(b(t)) &= \text{RHS}(B,A,\beta,\lambda,t) \cr
\text{LHS}(u(t)) &= \text{RHS}(B,A,\beta,\lambda,t) \cr
}$$

The four left-hand sides LHS() depend on four different functions of $t$ but have the same form.  The four right-hand sides are ***identical*** functions of the parameters $B,A,\beta,\lambda$ and the independent variable $t$.

So the system consists of four different things equal to the same thing. The only way for the system to be consistent is for the four different things to happen to turn out to be equal.  Which they aren't.  (It's easy to check because they are Laurent polynomials in $z=e^{it}$.)  Therefore the system is inconsistent.

If the physics of the source problem has a solution, I'd suggest there's an error somewhere in the Mathematica setup.  I don't know enough to say what, though.  I have some doubts that even one of the equations of the system could be solved, since the LHS on the face of it does not look analytic (or differentiable) and the RHS does.  I'm probably wrong about that, because I think that perhaps `d[t]`, `g[t]`, `b[t]`, `u[t]` are real-valued, making `Abs[]` unnecessary. In any case, it won't matter if the problem in the previous paragraph cannot be addressed.

Comment: You can take an average of the four functions resulting by $LHS(d(t)=0$, that would be  $LHS(d(t)+LHS(u(t)+LHS(y(t)+LHS(g(t))/4$, and it will still look too similar to $LHS(d(t))$. So the average of the LHS's is in fact close to $LHS(d(t))$. Therefore, if the system of equations in the OP should have a solution, it should be very similar to LHS(d(t)

Comment: @Vangsnes (1) `Solve` is an exact solver and does not do fitting or approximate solutions. So finding a function "close to" or "similar to" another requires a different approach. (2) You seem to say $\text{LHS}(d(t))=0$ and "the average of the LHS's is in fact close to $\text{LHS}(d(t))$: Why not say more simply that the average of the LHS's is in fact close to 0? I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Because I was looking for a type of solution. The average of LHS(d(t)) and all the other three is a messy function. The only pattern there is that there is a $E^{CIt}$ term everywhere in it.